# Invoking a JS method exposed by Flex app from a secondary window

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, internet-explorer-11, window.opener

I'm currently working on an old application made in Flex (so, basically, Flash) that is still required to work in IE11 (I know... I know). This webapp (let's call it A) exposes a method callable from JavaScript. A also has a button to open a new browser window (call it B). B has a listener on "beforeunload" event: when the user is going to close B, B has to call the JS method in A. Hope I explained it right. Using Google Chrome with the parameter "--disable-web-security" the method defined in A is executed and we're happy with that. We're using the following instruction:

`window.opener.document.getElementById('flashAppID').methodName();`

The issue we're facing is that IE11 throws the following Exception when B is trying to execute the JS method in A:

```
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: {
            [functions]: ,
            __proto__: null
         },
         message: "",
         name: "Error"
      },
      description: "Authorization denied",
      message: "Authorization denied",
      name: "Error",
      number: -2146828218,
      stack: "Error: Authorization denied
   at callOpener (http://domainname.ext/pageB.html:18:21)"
   }
```

We tried to disable any possible security restriction in IE but without luck; has anyone a suggestion on how to avoid that exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use HTTPS protocol for that site. If it is on other domain then try to enable 'Navigate windows and frames across different domains' and 'allow data sources across domains' options in IE options, security tab. For testing purpose, lower down the security settings of IE and keep settings similar for all security zones. Then again try to test the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Both pages are on the same domain. As I wrote, we already tried to lower all possible security settings of IE. I'm going to ask if we can use HTTPS. I'll let you know.

Comment: Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: I will, for sure. Please note that testing the behaviour in a page *without* the Flash app, the JS method is executed. So we can deduce that IE is blocking the interation between JS and Flash when the method is called from a secondary window.

Comment: If you are running this code in your organization than ask your IT department whether they had applied any security policies which is causing this issue. If possible for you than you can also try to test the same issue outside your organization to verify the result. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: We solved the issue. For unknown reasons, previous developers overwritten `document.domain` property. We commented that assignment and everything started to work as intended. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Its good to know that issue was resolved. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and  try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the following assignment, written for unknown reasons by previous developers:

```
document.domain = "domainname.ext";
```

After commenting that line, everything started to work as expected. So if anyone will face the same or similar issue, please be sure not to overwrite `document.domain` property.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.